# conversion from '_Complex float' to 'int' is not allowed in a converted constant expression

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf to exchange some messages but when i try to compile the code that uses the messages i am having this conversion error in the repeated field.h file, specifically in the code below.
Is it a version problem ?

.proto file

```
message mymessage {

    repeated double message = 20;
}
```

protobuf  repeated field.h

```
  template <int I>
  class FastAdderImpl<I, false> {
   public:
    explicit FastAdderImpl(RepeatedField* rf) : repeated_field_(rf) {}
    void Add(const Element& val) { repeated_field_->Add(val); }

   private:
    RepeatedField* repeated_field_;
    GOOGLE_DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(FastAdderImpl);
  };
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:473:17: error: expected ')'
  template <int I>
                ^
/usr/include/complex.h:53:11: note: expanded from macro 'I'
#define I _Complex_I
          ^
/usr/include/complex.h:48:21: note: expanded from macro '_Complex_I'
#define _Complex_I      (__extension__ 1.0iF)
                         ^
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:473:17: note: to match this '('
/usr/include/complex.h:53:11: note: expanded from macro 'I'
#define I _Complex_I
          ^
/usr/include/complex.h:48:20: note: expanded from macro '_Complex_I'
#define _Complex_I      (__extension__ 1.0iF)
                        ^


 error: conversion from '_Complex float' to 'int' is not allowed in a converted constant expression
  class FastAdderImpl<I, false> {
                      ^


/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h:474:23: error: conversion from '_Complex float' to 'int' is not allowed in a converted constant expression
  class FastAdderImpl<I, false> {
                      ^
/usr/include/complex.h:53:11: note: expanded from macro 'I'
#define I _Complex_I
          ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/complex.h:48:20: note: expanded from macro '_Complex_I'
#define _Complex_I      (__extension__ 1.0iF)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: That code in isolation means nothing. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Sure, i added. Tks for the time

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that a non-type template argument must be a **compile-time constant** but the type of the non-type template parameter(`int`) in your example is not the same as the type of the passed argument(`(__extension__ 1.0iF)`) and so requires a conversion.

Perhaps a contrived example might clear this up further:

```
constexpr float k = 4.4f;
template<int I> 
void f()
{

}
int main()
{
//----v----->not valid and will produce a similar error:conversion from 'float' to 'int' in a converted constant expression
    f<k>();
}
```

The above will produce a similar error saying:

```
conversion from 'float' to 'int' in a converted constant expression
could not convert 'k' from 'const float' to 'int'
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K66MEheT5)